# Can't connect to wireless network on Ubuntu Server

Tags: apt, wireless, 18.04

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 and ran into a problem when I tried to install network tools and the error message was:

```
failed to fetch archive.ubuntu/pool/main/w/wireless-tools/wireless-tools_30"pre9013ubuntu1_amd64.deb. Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
^ same thing again
unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try --fix missing
```

I ran `apt-get update` then:

```
Reloading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - Remove Caches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - Remove caches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Please tell us what options you have tried and give detailed descriptions of the results of those attempts. Also please provide the standard info: OS version, hardware...

Comment: @chili555 iwconfig is included in wireless tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried doing this before and it's a real pain. My suggestion is to either:

- Hook your Ubuntu Server installation to the internet using an Ethernet cable then install what you need (Preferred)
- On a separate machine use `apt download` and download all the necessary *.deb files into a folder on a flash drive (Make sure to remember dependencies!) then plug it into the Ubuntu Server and run `sudo apt install /path/to/dir/*` and have them all installed like that.

In general I would not suggest running a server hooked up to Wi-Fi. Use Ethernet instead because it's far more stable and the system will hook itself to the internet software-wise at boot up.

I am sure there are other ways to do what you want. But these two would probably be the most straight forward solution.

Comment: where exactly would i find these deb files?

Comment: When you use `apt download` pass it the package you want it to download (so if you wanted to download moon-buggy for example: `apt download moon-buggy`) it will download into your working directory.